# How do I get Eclipse to play nice with my SVN checkout?

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, svn-checkout

I have an SVN repository checked out and have an Eclipse project set up around it. When Eclipse builds it seems to be unsetting the svn:ignore '*' inside the output directory and also causing the source files to be copied into the output folders. Removing the directory and updating a new one from the repository fixes it until Eclipse builds again but it is annoying to have to do that every time I want to commit.

I have Eclipse set up to ignore .svn directories as described here:
http://www.damonkohler.com/2009/07/make-eclipse-ignore-svn-directories.html

Example `svn status`:

```
    S   classes
...
?       classes/dojo/Main$1.class
?       classes/dojo/Main$2.class
!       classes/dojo/Preferences.java
!       classes/dojo/Deck.java
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this like in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/8869/)?

> It looks like you use external build process which copies existing `.svn` folders from the source folders to the corresponding output folders (I think in this way because built-in Eclipse builder ignores team private resources like `.svn`).
>   This mean that in order to avoid the problem you should exclude `.svn` folders from your build process.

Comment: BASED ON WHAT? WHERE DO YOU GET THAT FROM WHAT HE POSTED? It doesn't matter if he's using an external builder, not that there is any indication that he is doing so. It's unsetting his ignore in the output directory because eclipse empties output directories (and therefore his svn:ignore gets cleared).

Comment: @JustinBuser Based on the OP's assesment of "causing the source files to be copied into the output folders". The thread I reference (I have fixed the link) exhibits similar symptoms and proposes a solution, in the off chance he is using an external builder within its Eclipse config. That may or not be the case, but anyway, the OP hasn't been seen on Stack Overflow for over 13 months now.

Comment: He said source files, you said .svn folders, neither of which would indicate an external builder. Depending on which svn adapter he's using the ignore property might be set inside a .svn folder in his output folder, which would get cleared when the directory is wiped upon building, he should set an ignore on the parent directory to omit the build dir entirely. Either way he specifically said that he set Eclipse to ignore .svn folders but it didn't solve the problem, so your _solution_ of "you should exclude .svn folders" is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to install a Eclipse Plugin for SVN usage like subclipse or Subversive.

Answer (score 0):

Are .svn and .svntemp checked in Window->Preferences->Team->Ignored Resources?